# Como simular un struct de C en Python

Tags: python

Quiero hacer es crear una clase llamado Persona que contenga dentro tres items (Nombre 'str' ,edad 'int' y dni 'int') a su vez tener una función aparte que se encargue de llenar esos campos a una Persona x y así guardar los datos de esa persona x dentro de un archivo como por ejemplo 'Personas.dat'. Que el código sea re-utilizable como para que cada vez que llame a la función pueda cargar cada vez mas personas.

Puedo mostrarles lo que quiero mediante codigo en C:

```
typedef struct
{
char nombreApellido[50];
int dni;
int edad;
} Persona;


Persona CargarStructP()
{
Persona a;
fflush(stdin);
printf("--->Ingrese nombre y apellido:\n");
gets((a).nombreApellido);
printf("--->Ingrese DNI:\n");
scanf("%i",&(a).dni);
printf("--->Ingrese edad:\n");
scanf("%i",&(a).edad);
printf("\n");
return a;
}

void CargarPersonas()
{
FILE *registroP = fopen("Personas.dat", "ab");
char control = 's';
Persona a;
while(control == 's' )
{
    a= CargarStructP();
    fwrite(&a, sizeof (Paciente), 1, registroP);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("Desea continuar [s/n]");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c", &control);
}
fclose(registroP);
}

void MostrarPersonas(Persona a)
{
printf("----------------------------------------------------");
printf("\n");
printf("PERSONA");
printf("\n");
printf("-Nombre y apellido : %s", a.nombreApellido);
printf("\n");
printf("-DNI: %i",a.dni);
printf("\n");
printf("-Edad: %i", a.edad);
printf("\n");
printf("----------------------------------------------------");
}
```

Bueno básicamente seria cargar datos a una clase que en este caso es Personas y eso guardarlo en un archivo  y que cada dato se guarde específicamente en una persona X. Si alguno sabe como expresar esto en Python o si puede darme algún TIP sobre como llegar aproximadamente a un resultado similar le estaría muy agradecido. Desde ya muchísimas gracias a todos!

Comment: Hola Gerónimo. Para que podamos ayudarte has de haberlo intentado y mostrarnos tus problemas concretos. Si ya tienes el codigo C solo tienes que ir *traduciendo*. Pulsa en [edit] para explicar tus dudas y tus intentos siguiendo [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo

Comment: Creo que tu pregunta es demasiado amplia. Has preguntado básicamente tres cosas: 1) Cuál es el equivalente en python  de un struct en C. 2) ¿Como leer varios datos de ese tipo? y 3) ¿Cómo guardarlos en fichero?. He respondido más abajo a la primera cuestión, y ya ves que tienes varias posibilidades. Elige una, e intenta seguir tú con la pregunta 2) que no debería ser muy difícil (puedes crear listas de tuplas, o de diccionarios o de objetos). La 3) depende de qué formato concreto quieras guarda. En todo caso, eso sería material para otra pregunta y no esta. Edita por favor esta para reducirla.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python no tiene estructuras, pero tiene varios otros tipos de datos que pueden usarse para lo mismo. Te indico algunas posibilidades:

### Tuplas (desaconsejado)

Una tupla es un grupo de datos, entre paréntesis y separados por comas. Cada elemento de la tupla puede ser de un tipo diferente. Entonces una persona podría ser una tupla de tres valores, el nombre, el DNI y la edad. Así:

```
persona = ("Manolo", 108761234, 23)
```

Puedes acceder a los campos particulares de la tupla por el lugar que ocupan, como si fueran un array del C. Así `persona[0]` sería el nombre, `persona[1]` el DNI, etc. Python sabe como imprimir directamente una tupla sin que tengas que iterar por ella:

```
>>> print(persona)
("Manolo", 108761234, 23)
```

La tupla una vez creada no se puede modificar. Esto puede ser útil en muchos casos, pero en otros no. Depende del uso que vayas a darle.

El gran inconveniente de la tupla es que es poco legible, pues hay que recordar en que orden están almacenados los datos para poder referirse a ellos.

### Diccionarios

Un diccionario se parece en la sintaxis a un array del C, pues a sus elementos se accede poniendo entre corchetes el "indice", sólo que en este caso el "indice" no tiene por qué ser entero, sino que puede ser de muchos otros tipos. Un caso particular es usar cadenas como "índice" (en realidad, en los diccionarios los "indices" se llaman *claves*), y así esas cadenas serían equivalentes a los nombres de los campos de una estructura C.

Por ejemplo:

```
persona = {}  # Esto es un diccionario vacío
persona["nombre"] = "Manolo"
persona["dni"] = 108761234
persona["edad"] = 23
```

Python sabe como imprimir directamente diccionarios, si bien el orden en que aparecen sus campos no es predecible (salvo a partir de Python 3.7+, que respeta el orden en que fueron asignados).

```
>>> print(persona)
{'nombre': 'Manolo', 'dni': 108761234, 'edad': 23}
```

### Objetos

Usando programación orientada a objetos, puedes definir una clase `Persona`, que tenga atributos para los datos que quieres guardar, y métodos para operar sobre esos campos. Sintácticamente esto es lo que más se parece a una estructura del C.

En python podrías declarar la clase persona de forma tan simple como:

```
class Persona:
   pass
```

Esto crea una clase sin ningún atributo ni método. No obstante, ya que en Python todo es dinámico, puedes crear atributos a posteriori, al instanciar esta clase en un objeto y añadirle a ese objeto la información deseada:

```
persona = Persona()  # Crea un objeto nuevo, a partir de esa clase
persona.nombre = "Manolo"
persona.dni = 108761234
persona.edad = 23
# Se le asignan atributos
```

No obstante no es esta la forma habitual de trabajar. Lo normal es que los atributos se asignen al objeto a través de su *constructor* que es una función que se ejecuta cuando se crea un nuevo objeto de esa clase, y que puede recibir como parámetros los datos en cuestión, para que los guarde en los correspondientes atributos.

En python el constructor se escribe añadiendo un método llamado `__init__()` a la clase. Este método recibe como mínimo un primer parámetro llamado `self` que representa al objeto que está siendo creado, y luego todos los parámetros adicionales que quieras ponerle. En nuestro caso:

```
class Persona:
    def __init__(self, nombre, dni, edad):
         self.nombre = nombre
         self.dni = dni
         self.edad = edad
```

Con el constructor, la creación de un objeto sería así:

```
persona = Persona("Manolo", 108761234, 23)
```

Como ves se parece en cierto modo a la tupla inicial, pero ahora con la ventaja de que para acceder a los datos se usa el nombre de los atributos en lugar de su posición (que en realidad no existe). Es decir, `persona.edad` valdría 23 (`persona[2]` no existe).

Python por defecto "no sabe" cómo imprimir un objeto, lo que te imprime es la clase a que pertenece y la dirección de memoria en que está guardado:

```
>>> print(persona)
<__main__.Persona at 0x7fc0b2d1cfd0>
```

Esto no es muy útil, pero puedes definir tu propio método `__str__()`, dentro de la clase `Persona` que devuelva una cadena, y entonces Python usará ese método cuando tenga que imprimirlo.

Hay muchísimo más que contar sobre programación orientada a objetos (OOP) pero no es este el lugar. Debes leer cualquiera de los muchos tutoriales que hay sobre programación en Python.

### Namedtuples

Cuando una clase se va a usar sólo para guardar información, y no para proporcionar funcionalidad, es decir, cuando queremos puramente el equivalente a un `struct` del C, podemos usar el tipo `namedtuple`, que es mix entre una tupla y una clase. Internamente almacena los datos en una tupla, pero permite acceder a ellos por su nombre además de por su posición.

Es especialmente indicado para el caso en que queremos además que los datos sean *inmutables* (que no puedan modificarse una vez se han guardado).

Ejemplo de este caso:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Persona = namedtuple("Persona", ["nombre", "dni", "edad"])
# Persona es una clase, de la que puedo instanciar objetos
persona = Persona(nombre="Manolo", dni=108761234, edad=23)
```

Ahora puedes acceder al nombre tanto por `persona[0]` como por `persona.nombre`.

Además, la clase `Persona` creada con `namedtuple()` incorpora métodos para que al imprimir el objet la representación sea fácilmente legible:

```
>>> print(persona)
Persona(nombre='Manolo', dni=108761234, edad=23)
```

Comment: Impresionante! Te agradezco muchísimo por el tiempo que te tomaste en explicarme ya mismo apunte todo el texto por que realmente es de mucha ayuda tanto para mi que soy principiante como para las muchas personas que están iniciando en este mundo de la programación, ahora mismo intentare resolverlo mediante Objetos y Namedtuples así de paso voy practicándolo. Gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!