# Registros Jerárquicos de c++ en python

Tags: python, c++, array

Me encuentro con un inconveniente,estoy buscando el equivalente en python de un registro jerárquico de lenguaje C++, Los registros son los siguiente en c++:

```
struct Fecha
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
};

struct Informacion
{
    int codigo;
    float precio;
    Fecha ingreso,nacimiento; //aquí esta el vinculo con "struct fecha"
    char descripcion[40];   
};
```

A su vez, es un arreglo de registro, en el main() se declara:

```
Informacion arreglo[40];
```

El problema, no estoy encontrando su equivalente en python, eh buscado pero no encuentro la solución, no tengo muy claro cómo planterlo en python

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como simular un struct de C en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225573/como-simular-un-struct-de-c-en-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias alternativas para implementar estructuras de C en Python.

Lo más fácil es simplemente usar un diccionario:

```
fecha = dict(day=10, month=3, year=2020)
```

Si quieres ser un poco más estricto, puedes implementar una clase:

```
class Fecha:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

f = Fecha()
f.day = 10
f.month = 20
f.year = 2020
```

Eso es lo mínimo exigible. La única ventaja adicional es que ahora queda claro que `f` es un objeto tipo `Fecha`, no un simple diccionario.

Los objetos en Python son básicamente diccionarios enchulados. No exigen getters ni setters. Puedes agregar nuevas llaves y cambiar valores directamente. No existe los datos/metodos privados en Python, aunque hay convenciones de nomenclatura para expresar esa idea.

La ventaja de las clases en Python es que puedes implementar métodos *mágicos* para facilitar el uso de los objetos: impresión, serialización, operaciones de comparación, etc (igual que el overload en C++).

Ejemplo. El método `__str__` es llamado cuando Python necesita imprimir un objeto:

```
class Fecha:
    def __init__(self, day, month, year):
        self.day = day
        self.month = month
        self.year = year

    def __str__(self):
        return "%02d/%02d/%04d" % (self.day, self.month, self.year)
    
f = Fecha(10, 20, 2020)
print(f)
```

produce

```
10/20/2020
```

En Python los arreglos no se declaran. Como no se declaran, pueden crecer sin restricciones, tanto en número de elementos como en dimensiones. Simplemente los creas y luego le vas agregando elementos.

Ejemplo:

```
ultimos_12_meses = []
ultimos_12_meses.append(Fecha(1, 1, 2019))
```

Answer (score 2):

En Python se pueden instanciar los atributos de una clase de manera similar a la definición de variables en una estructura de datos (struct en C), por medio de [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Pienso que esa es la manera más simulable, digo esto ya que se hace a través de una clase (que no es lo mismo que una estructura de datos):

**En C:**

```
typedef struct Gato {
    char *color;
    int edad;
    char *duenio;
} Gato;

int main(void) {
    Gato Ursula;

    Ursula.color = "Naranja";
    Ursula.edad = 6;
    Ursula.duenio = "Rodolfo";

    return 0;
}
```

O bien

```
struct Gato {
    char *color;
    int edad;
    char *duenio;
};

int main(void) {
    struct Gato Ursula;

    Ursula.color = "Naranja";
    Ursula.edad = 6;
    Ursula.duenio = "Rodolfo";

    return 0;
}
```

**En Python:**

```
class Gato():
    __slots__ = ["Color","Edad","Duenio"]

Ursula = Gato()
Ursula.Color = "Naranja"
Ursula.Edad = 6
Ursula.Duenio = "Rodolfo"
```

Desconozco si hay una manera en Python de inicializar los atributos de un objeto por medio de una lista (Como en C con un array)

**Profundizando, ¿Cómo funciona `__slots__`?**

Como ya dije, `__slots__` te permite instanciar los atributos de una clase de manera similar a los structs en C. Esto por medio de una lista (la definición de `__slots__`), los strings que debe de contener la lista van a ser interpretados como los nombres de las variables que representan atributos.

La sentencia

```
class Gato():
    __slots__ = ["Color","Edad","Duenio"]
```

es equivalente a

```
class Gato():
    def __init__(self,Color,Edad,Duenio):
        self.Color = Color
        self.Edad = Edad
        self.Duenio = Duenio
```

**¿Qué diferencias hay entre esto?**

La principal diferencia es que `__init__` es un método que se invoca cuando se inicializa un objeto en base a dicha clase, `__init__` depende de parámetros a la hora de inicializar el objeto para definir atributos. Esto no es necesario en todos los casos, ya que aveces se pueden definir atributos de manera interna sin depender de variables o valores externos a la clase.

Por otro lado, `__slots__` es una constante dentro de la clase que instancia todos los atributos (por medio de la lista que se usa). Por esto mismo se tiene que definir sus valores de manera externa a la clase:

```
Ursula = Gato()
Ursula.Color = "Naranja"
Ursula.Edad = 6
Ursula.Duenio = "Rodolfo"
```

**¿Cuál debo o es más conveniente de usar?**

`__slots__` no define valores en espacio de memoria al instante, **solo los instancia**. Deja abierta la posibilidad de definirlos.

Respondiendo a la pregunta, es mejor usar el método `__init__()` para inicializar el objeto con atributos necesarios desde su inicialización. Por otro lado, `__slots__` cuando no son necesarios ciertos atributos desde la inicialización del objeto, o bien no se sabe si tiene que inicializar.

**Enlaces que te pueden servir:**

Creo que esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225573/como-simular-un-struct-de-c-en-python) (que ya es vieja) te puede ayudar.

- [La referencia de los modelos de datos en Python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/225573/como-simular-un-struct-de-c-en-python)

Espero te haya servido, saludos!

Comment: Por favor, amplia tu respuesta para explicar que son y cómo se usan los __slots__.

Comment: Listo @CandidMoe

Comment: Si,quedo bien explicado.